# Does the new measurement of the fine structure constant rule out string theory?

Tags: experimental-physics, electrons, string-theory, magnetic-moment

I am no expert in either string theory or experimental physics, but I was reading [this article](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-03314-0) by Nature, where it is quoted:

> This result confirms, for example, that the electron has no substructure and is truly an elementary particle. If it were made of smaller constituents, it would have a different magnetic moment, contrary to observation.

Of course, we are still a long way from making precision measurements at the Planck scale, where strings are postulated to "reside". But still, as the articles states, wouldn't the fact that electrons are actually made up of strings have some effect on the magnetic moment calculation? And if so, isn't this new measurement (which matches the standard calculation) evidence that electrons are not constituted of strings?

Comment: Why would the new value rule out string theory if the old, not-much-different value did not?

Comment: Experimentally (probably) you can never say that something is truly elementary. They definitely put bounds on the scale at which the electron can be considered as elementary

Answer (score 0):

This is not how string theory works. In string theory, there are *no such things as elementary particles*. In the context of string theory, calling an electron a fundamental particle is not exactly correct. Instead, since particles are described by vibrating strings, each  string has a vibrational mode corresponding  to a different particle. That is, all elementary particles can arise as different vibrations of this single elementary string, and these modes determine the particles properties like charge, mass and therefore moment.

In the current understanding of string theory, these strings are not made of anything. They *are* the fundamental constituents of matter.

It’s also important to note that [string theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory) is still a model that has no experimental evidence, unlike the [standard model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics which is experimentally verified up to a miraculously high accuracy.